# cognito pool - failed to signup a user

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to build a user management based on cognito user pool.
I am using nodesjs + express for the backend, all the operation to cognito will be done from the nodejs.

my signup route is

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
let userName = req.body.userName;
let email = req.body.email;
let familyName = req.body.familyName;
let password = req.body.password;

let attributeList = [];

let dataEmail = {
    Name: 'email',
    Value: email
};

let name = {
    Name: 'name',
    Value: userName
};

let familyname = {
    Name: 'family_name',
    Value: familyName
};

let attributeEmail = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
let attributeName = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(name);
let attributeFamilyName = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute(familyname);

attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
attributeList.push(attributeName);
attributeList.push(familyname);

let userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
userPool.signUp(email, password, attributeList, null, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(`got error during signup ${err}`);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    } else {
        let cognitoUser = result.user;
        console.log('user name is ' + cognitoUser.getUsername());
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }

   });

});
```

however I am getting a failure and cannot find how to over come it
the error is missing parameter:

got error during signup MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Username' in params

Answer (score 0):

A 'username' attribute is always required to register a user. So you'll need to add one to the attributes list.

If you're not asking the users for a username or don't need one for your use case, you can just use whatever value your using to uniquely identify the user. Thats a simple way to handle it.

So for example, on top of adding their email address to the email address attribute, submit it as the username attribute too.

Reference:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html